# Q:get a view's constrains returns empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

First I show my `cell` , my label has several `constaints`:

---

[image: constrains]

---

In my `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

I get the `label`'s constrains :

`NSArray *cons = (((NoticeAnnouncementCell*)cell).mainTitle).constraints;`

but I get a empty array.

Comment: does cell.constraints/ cell.contentView.constraints  return nil too ?

Comment: You should first create the instance of NoticeAnnouncementCell and then access the constraint of the label as NSArray *constraintOfMainTitleLabel = cell.mainTitleLable.constraints;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create an instance of cell and then access the constraint of label as below,

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = (UITableViewCell*) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:10];
    NSArray *arrayOfLableConstraint = [label constraints];

}
```

By this you will get constraint only set to the label itself like width and height or any alignment constraint, to get all the constraint you should access the cell's constraint, don't worry about how to find labels constraint only out of other views, you can do that easily by just setting identifier for the constraints you set for the label.

***You can set the identifier to the constraint by simply selecting the constraint individually and set the identifier from size inspector as show below,***

[image]

Hope that helps you...

Comment: I have test your method, and I think your function is good ,but there it is no use for my issue, and thank you again.

Comment: What is your issue then, i have answered to your questions only, that is you are not able to access the constraint of the label. And could you explain why you want to access the constraint that way because if you want to modify any specific constraint as in the image you provided, if you want to modify the verticalSpace/topSpace constraint then you can simply create an outlet of that constant and no need to loop through each and every constraint.

Comment: thanks your patient， my issue is I get the `label's` contraints ,it shows empty array. I willl upvote your answer it is a good answer for finding constraint.

Comment: I outlet the constant, it is ok, I upvote wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to get the constraints from superView?

```
NSArray *constraints = cell.constraints;
```

or

find constraint in subviews

```
NSArray *subviews = cell.subviews;

[subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
   if (obj.constraints.count == 0) {
      return;
   }

   NSLog(@"%@", obj);
   NSLog(@"%@", obj.constraints);

}];
```

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri.If I get the supperView's `constaints`, how can I know which is the `label's` constaint?